# Why do BLM protestors continue after all four police involved in the killing of George Floyd are facing charges?

Tags: united-states, protests, police, racism

Why do BLM protestors continue to protest now that all four police involved in the killing of George Floyd are facing charges and police around the country are being held accountable (e.g. the 6 Atlanta officers who got arrested for police brutality)? I am wondering what tangible change is currently being asked for. Police departments around the country are already starting to take action against racism. What’s the next step?

Comment: "I am wondering what tangible change is currently being asked for" have you been listening? What research have you done on this topic?

Answer (score 37):

Do you really think the problem is limited to those 4? Why on earth would someone sit on a handcuffed person's neck for 9 minutes, 3 of which that person having no pulse? with 3 colleagues watching? How were these people trained?  How are they monitored for use of reasonable force? There is something seriously wrong with the level of violence US cops sometimes apply to people they interact with. Yes, black people are the biggest victims, yes black people are angry, and yes, black lives matter. But this extends to many victims of police overreaction. As a, white, tourist in the US, my car was once almost shot at because I did not have my lights on at dusk. We are all George Floyd.

It is high time there is a systemic change so that police are held accountable, and, more importantly, that police departments everywhere train their people not to use deadly force unless necessary.

Minnesota is suing its own police department.  What there needs to happen is that police departments as a whole, not just their bad apples, get sued, heavily, when unreasonable force is applied, especially if it is shown that the officers carrying out those acts were mostly behaving in line according to an customary level of **excessively violent response for a given department**.    Given big enough punitive awards, police departments will have to insure for the risks and insurance companies will be the first to point the finger at badly run departments.

Had Chauvin been on his own?  Yes, putting him in jail would fix things.  But look at the context - he was not worried about his behavior crossing the line, with 3 colleagues there.  Look at [the, white, guy who got swatted and killed about a few years ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Wichita_swatting).  He was no threat to cops who were behind their cars and had their guns on him.

Look at the numerous reports of intimidation and physical violence against reporters.  Does that sound like a well-run state, as envisioned by the Founding Fathers?

All US citizens, not just black people, would benefit from having less violent cops.  Further down the line, even the cops would benefit from having a population that would trust them more.  A lot of this really seems to boil down to a group culture of tolerance of violence that is totally unacceptable from people who are paid by the citizens to protect them.  And it is not even doing the cops a favor:  people react according to what the norm is with their peers.  With better peers, Chauvin may or may not have killed Floyd.

So, yes, it makes sense to insist on real changes, because there is a long list of very similar events preceding this one, with no changes made.

Maybe your question should have been.  *Hey, now that [Freddie Gray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_of_Freddie_Gray)'s cops are being put on trial, why bother being angry?*.  Or *[Michael Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_of_Michael_Brown) has had his justice served, so chill, will ya?*

I actually don't dislike cops.  I think they do a necessary job.  It is sad, and disturbing, to see all the people calling them bullies and racists (the Freddie Gray killing involved at least 1 or 2 black policemen, out of 6).   US citizens need their police, but they also all need *better* police.

But it is easy in their line of work to dehumanize people you are dealing with.  Maybe you just arrest too many junkie muggers, of whatever color, and they get released.  So you crack on the next person.  Who knows?   That needs to be recognized as an occupational risk and carefully managed so that it doesn't turn into these macho shoot first, ask questions later.  And people who can't manage to keep their aggression down need to be fired.  So should people who can't quite be neutral about which ethnic group a citizen belongs to.

And, yes, black people, much more so than whites, are very much the first in the line of fire and have every right to insist on changes.  But unless you are really really not a type to be seen as threatening, say if you are the proverbial little old white lady, then BLM may actually be doing you a favor.

p.s. you know the one thing that's really driving this stuff?  Cell phones cameras.  20 years ago, I'm sure it just happened and no one saw any evidence contradicting the official version.

p.p.s.  *are being held accountable* isn't really strictly true.  They are being *charged* and will be *indicted*.  Whether they get *convicted* is an entirely different story and, on past experience, rather unlikely.

For example, in the F. Gray case, none of the 6 officers got convicted.  Ditto M. Brown.

A little infographic illustrates this better, comes from https://mappingpoliceviolence.org/ which has more data.  Sure, with a name like *mappingpoliceviolence.org*, one might expect them to be biased.  But... are they factually wrong?

[image]

FWIW, Canada, with 10x less population, [had 460 people killed by police, from 2000 to 2017](https://newsinteractives.cbc.ca/longform-custom/deadly-force), i.e. more than twice the above duration and we're less than happy with those numbers.  My ballpark estimate is that's a rate per capita 3 or 4 smaller than the US.

Comment: I don't think disarming American cops to follow the UK's model of unarmed police would be a good idea, since American criminals are much more heavily armed than the UK's criminals are. It'd be open season on police officers.

Comment: @nick012000 It's the snowball effect/arms race argument.  Arm the police to the teeth, and the crooks arm themselves to the teeth in response.  Make the police poorly armed, and the crooks don't need to outfit themselves like a swat team, and proceed to do so to save costs and visibility.  Lesser armaments suffice to achieve the same level of success as before. And conversely if the crooks deescalated their weaponry the police could respond in kind, but simple fact is we don't control what crooks do *by definition*, but we do control what cops do (also rather by definition).

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Alternately, the crooks continue to be armed, and simply kill any cops who try to stop them. The current situation is basically the result of the Second Amendment working as intended.

Comment: @nick012000 Yes, not everyone agrees with the argument, especially those who are staunch supporters of a broad interpretation of the 2nd amendment, but it is frequently put out there.  But really, the crooks have little to no incentive to just kill cops simply because they can at that moment when they are not threatened with death, either.  Most people, especially those trained for the situation, will avoid aggravating someone threatening them with a lethal weapon when they can't do the same. Killing the cops just aggravates their offense and makes it less likely they'll get away.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy I think you're underestimating how bloodthirsty drug cartels are. If they could get away with slaughtering cops en masse, they totally would - just look at what they do in Mexico.

Comment: @nick012000  I most certainly wouldn't suggest disarming the police to UK levels.  But bringing in Mexican cartels to argue that things are hunky-dory in the US wrt police usage of violence smells strongly of strawman arguments.  And the circumstances of Floyd's death have nada, zilch, to do with Mexican cartels.  Funny how 2nd amendment is, by lotsa folk, argued as needed to *prevent* an oppressive state.  And in your case, to *provide cover for* oppressive acts by *some* of the police.  Can you clarify that for me?

Comment: but to avoid this kinda reframing, taking out the reference to UK kill rates.  better?

Comment: Crooks in the U.K. know that bringing a gun is a very, very bad idea. Because a gun will get an armed response unit coming after you and they have _more_ guns and know how to use them.

Comment: I don't know why the discussion here is entirely about disarmament. The answer never mentions disarmament. In fact, guns are a total red herring when it comes to police brutality. George Floyd wasn't shot and neither was Eric Garner. The guns aren't the problem, the cops holding the guns are the problem.

Comment: Do you not think that enforcing criminal penalties against officers who commit crimes is of primary importance?  Because if it is, then the actions currently taken by MN are exactly right.

Comment: @F1Krazy - They are not a *total* red herring considering that the majority of police homicides involve guns, and that in countries with much lower levels of guns there are fewer police homicides. Racism in the police force and other structural and personal factors are the root causes, but they are many intervening factors that make the root causes more lethal.

Comment: @Obie2.0 they are a red herring in the sense that I did not talk about disarming cops in the least bit.  Like I said, reframing and diverging conversation from police accountability to me supposedly advocating disarming them.

Comment: @mbsq Hard to answer in a way that does not upset people.  Of course, Chauvin should be judged for this killing.  No question.  However, in my opinion, the most meaningful legacy of Floyd's death would be not so much punishment of his killer as using it to push systemic reform so that it doesn't happen again.  The state suing the city's police force and the city council vowing to disband it *are* great developments, especially if it holds the whole Minneapolis PD accountable and unmasks similar PDs across the country.  Throwing Chauvin in jail should not absolve PD-level guilt.

Comment: @Italian Isn’t deterrence important?

Comment: @mbsq I believe you'll get more wrongful death reduction from forcing police departments to train & practice safer, less violent, policing than from dissuading individual police officers.  Chauvin's choke doesn't result in death *most of the time*, so, if the PD says it's OK to choke someone suspected of a non-violent crime and already restrained in handcuff, an individual policeman may still make wrong decisions.  A PD needs to step back and say *no way this should be done to someone, **ever**, if there is no threat to someone's life*.  And verify claims of "threats to life" if it happens.

Comment: In Canada for example, after a few too many innocent bystanders killed in high speed car chases, the police is told **not** to initiate a high speed car chase unless they have reasons to believe people's lives are put in danger by not doing so.  Basically, for a lot of low-level nuisance crime, there is very little societal benefit from the police engaging in high risk activities to "catch their man".  Someone driving a stolen car doesn't deserve to get shot at, for example.  Someone driving a stolen car after a bank robbery? Yes.  Street corner dope peddler?  No.  Cartel hitman?  Yes.

Comment: @mbsq isn't the point of the data in the original answer, and the whole underlaying message of the BLM movement and these protests in particular that the statement "Minnesota is following through on this crucial element" needs "this time" added to the end of it?

Answer (score 12):

tl;dr: The death of George Floyd was not an isolated incident, it's the larger system people want to change.

1. These 4 officers were *charged*, but *convictions* in police misconduct cases are exceedingly rare.  See for example [Five Thirty Eight's statistics](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/why-its-still-so-rare-for-police-officers-to-face-legal-consequences-for-misconduct/), and [the riots after the police charged with use of excessive force on Rodney King were acquitted](https://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/riots-erupt-in-los-angeles) (back when videos of police in action were rare.).
2. Even in protests against a filmed incident of apparently excessive force, there have been hundreds of recorded incidents that appear to show excessive use of force, police targeting journalists, and disturbing attitudes displayed by police (like the Buffalo cop who yelled "F*ck the First Amendment" at a news photographer. [(Photographer's Twitter statement.](https://twitter.com/PhotoJazzy/status/1269057353892212743))) Many people seem to be realizing that the US justice system system is systematically flawed.
3. There is a feeling in some circles that this is a narrow window to get needed systematic reform enacted, and protests are a meaningful way for Americans to get government attention and action.
4. We don't actually know [how many people die in police custody each year](https://journalistsresource.org/studies/government/criminal-justice/deaths-police-custody-united-states/), but there is a widespread perception that there are many cases where abuse of police power is covered up.

OP said:

> Police departments around the country are already starting to take action against racism.

I don't see that.  I see *some* police departments in *some* cities making *statements* about racism. Not at all the same thing.  People said policing would change after Rodney King. After Freddie Gray. After Tamir Rice. After Breonna Taylor. Yet here we are.

There have been some changes in policing in recent years, for example the widespread adoption of body cams, [which have mixed results](https://www.govtech.com/biz/What-Bodycams-Do-Behavior-Accountability-and-Trust.html), especially when [police can turn them off at will](https://www.newsweek.com/chicago-mayor-calls-out-officers-who-turn-off-body-cams-says-we-will-strip-you-your-police-1509167) (sometimes [in violation of published policies.](https://blogs.findlaw.com/blotter/2018/04/can-police-turn-off-body-cameras.html)) -- but there are also legitimate privacy issues to deal with. (A full discussion of [the pros and cons](https://bja.ojp.gov/sites/g/files/xyckuh186/files/bwc/pdfs/north-carolina-district-attorneys_best-practices-committee_body-worn-cameras-concerns-and-considerations.pdf) of this one point is beyond the scope here.)

In any case, there is a growing public perception that this is a systematic issue which needs a systematic solution, not piecemeal changes in one city or another. [Seattle's chief of police called for reform in 2018](https://www.aclu.org/blog/criminal-law-reform/reforming-police/honoring-police-includes-acknowledging-systemic-reform), but some of the worst of this week's offenses caught on camera have come from Seattle.

Comment: There actually have been a lot of reforms put into place. For example, recent events have involved body camera footage, and these were implemented largely since 2014.  Google what Minneapolis has done since the advent of BLM.  Reforms cannot eliminate 100% of police crimes, so the statement, “Yet here we are,” would seem to be applicable at any time.

Comment: @mbsq And yet police routinely turn off their body cameras before going into loaded situations. Several of the cases people talk about right now involved turned off cameras, and police face no consequences for turning them off. It was at best an empty gesture.

Comment: @Johanna An empty gesture? Yes the absence of regulations forcing them to be on is bad, but do you have a better idea? Camera crew in tow?

Comment: There are suggestions for things like removing the presumption that an officer is acting in good faith after they turn off their body cam, but that's getting pretty far from the original question.

Comment: I think it could be incredibly influential in shaping public opinion. When a police officer has to wear a body camera - and, even more so, when they turn it off before committing a crime - that signals to the public that they have something to hide. The presumption of truth is diminished. It's a sign that officers will not be believed off the bat anymore. Besides, cases such as that of Floyd have shown the importance of having video, and even if police disable their cameras before many incidents, they do not *always* do it, and in the cases where they do not, the recordings serve as evidence.

Comment: Unfortunately, @Obie2.0, there is no track record of penalties for body cams that are turned off or conveniently fail at critical moments.

Comment: I am not talking about penalties for having them disabled, but more the effect on public awareness. I think that if just one body camera records video of an instance of police brutality that makes its way to the public and makes them more aware of the racial disparities in policing (as many have), they will have arguably served their purpose.

Comment: @obie *Why not* have penalties for turning them off? This should be an important part of the system, no?

Comment: What you wrote kinda makes sense. The only problem with that is that there is no connection between what you wrote and BLM-led protests. Just think that now (unlike earlier) BLM itself does not have any official manifesto. No goals. Just blacklivesmatter which is not enough to get anywhere near civil or criminal code. You gotta be more articulated than a hashtag.

Comment: Unfortunately, matcheek, long articulate statements don't get attention but catchy slogans do.

Answer (score 3):

The killing of George Floyd was a disgusting act caught on video and widely published.  The video produced a strong emotional reaction which spurred many people to action (to do something, anything, right now), and the emotion seemed to sustain itself.  Soon, the focus of the protest moved almost completely beyond the facts of the case involving Floyd.  Because Floyd was black and the officer (Chauvin) who killed him was white, it was taken as a starting point to talk about racism in society, and of the foundations of law enforcement.  The agenda of this discussion has very little to do with pursuing criminal justice against Chauvin.  Thus one cannot expect at this point for any developments in the Floyd case to influence the direction of the protest movement.

Comment: Re *"The agenda of this discussion..."*: as currently phrased, it almost sounds like this' answer is arguing that the public wouldn't have cared about the result if George Floyd had all along had white skin, but every other fact and outcome was the same.